# Spring trying to set audit fields on null object

Tags: spring, null, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, auditing

Spring-data-mongodb is trying to add createdDate to a null object and fails to do so. How do I configure spring audit to ignore null objects so it does not try to add audit fields to it?

I have an abstract class with all the audit info. Two classes (A,B) extend this abstract class and one of those two classes (A) has a reference to the other class (B) (that can be nullable). If I try to save an object of A with a null reference to B. It all fails because spring is trying to add audit info to the B null reference.

```
public abstract class AA {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Version
    private Long version;
    @CreatedDate
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;
    @LastModifiedDate
    private LocalDateTime LastModifiedDate;
}

public class A extends AA {
   private String name;
   @Nullable
   private B b;
}

public class B extends AA {
   private String name;
}

public class ControllerA {

    private AMongoRepository aMongoRepo;

    public void saveSomeA(String name) {
        A a = new A();
        a.setName("Some Name");
        a.setB(null);
        aMongoRepo.save(a); // <-- Fails can not set createdDate on B null
    }
}
```

The error message I get is the following.

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Cannot lookup property B A.b on null intermediate! Original path was: b.createdDate on A.
```

A quick google search brought me to [jira.spring.io](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1461), which is the same issue I am having.

Any idea on how to cleanly handle this issue? Maybe move from inheritance to composition? Or should I just be patient an wait on the new version?

Comment: Do you got solve this ? I have same problem.

Comment: @JetersonMirandaGomes I didn't dig any deeper into it and just left the audit info out for now. In the linked Jira ticket, they say it should be resolved in newer versions starting at 2.1.4 (Lovelace SR4) and 2.2 M2 (Moore).

Comment: Hi I'm having some issue there , How did you resolve it ?